# Error connecting to MySQL: Error: Handshake inactivity timeout mysql native react

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to connect mysql with native react.
I am trying to view the contents from the database but keep getting a timeout error. I am convinced that my mysql credentials are correct.

Is there something I am missing ?

I followed this tutorial https://dev.to/saulojoab/how-to-get-data-from-an-mysql-database-in-react-native-53a4

package.json

```
{
      "name": "check",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
        "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
        "expo": "~46.0.16",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
        "react": "18.0.0",
        "react-native": "0.69.6",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.5.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "https://github.com/ram33z/react-native-snap-carousel"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
      },
      "private": true
    }
```

route.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();
const connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'check',
    database: 'mydata',
});


// Test the MySQL connection
connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting to MySQL:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to MySQL database');
        connection.release();
    }
});

// Creating a GET route that returns data from the 'test' table.
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'test' table).
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM mydata.test', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error executing MySQL query:', error);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        } else {
            res.send(results);
        }
    });
});

// Starting our server.
app.listen(3306, () => {
    console.log('Go to http://localhost:3306/test to see the data.');
});
```

error:

```
Error connecting to MySQL: Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:160:17)
    at Handshake.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Handshake._onTimeout (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:124:8)
    at Timer._onTimeout (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js:32:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/raheem/Documents/route.js:13:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: 10000
}
Error executing MySQL query: Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:160:17)
    at Handshake.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Handshake._onTimeout (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:124:8)
    at Timer._onTimeout (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js:32:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/Users/rasheed/Documents/app/team_08-main/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
    at /Users/raheem/Documents/app/route.js:25:16
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/raheem/Documents/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: 10000
}
```